# Running ftools multiparts to singleparts from PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, ftools

Is it possible to run the *multiparts to singleparts* function from the console with the `processing_runalg` function?

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

1) The proposed solution ([Using processing algorithms from the console](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html))

```
 import processing
 # find the algorithm
 processing.alglist("Multipart to singleparts")
 Multipart to singleparts----------------------------->qgis:multiparttosingleparts
 # help
 processing.alghelp("qgis:multiparttosingleparts")
 ALGORITHM: Multipart to singleparts  
    INPUT <ParameterVector>  
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

So the command is

```
processing.runalg("qgis:multiparttosingleparts","shape1.shp","shape2.shp")
```

2) an easiest solution

Each time you execute a Processing algorithm,the complete runalg command with values are saved in the *.../.qgis2/processing/processing.log* file

Execute the algorithm with a test layer and look at the last line of this file:

```
ALGORITHM|Mon Apr 14 2014    
17:13:45|processing.runalg("qgis:multiparttosingleparts","/Users/shape1.shp","/Users/shape2.shp")
```

and you have the syntax of the command.

Comment: thanks, it works perfect. A shame that you can't use layers from memory, but you need to save the .shp files first.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS3:

```
algSingle = processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:multiparttosingleparts",{'INPUT': prelayer, 'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(algSingle['OUTPUT'])
```