# Exploding multipart features in qgis using python

Tags: qgis, python, multipart, explode

I want to explode a multipart layer to singlepart in python. I see through the qgis gui there is a way to do it under vector--geometry--tools--Multipart to Singleparts.. which does what I need, I just need the python code for this. I'm new to qgis.

Comment: thanks I didn't see that post, that seems to do the trick! Sorry you felt the need to downvote if I did search for the answer

Comment: It's not safe to assume that those who left helpful comments are those that down-voted; complaints about down-voting (especially to those who are probably innocent) might in turn generate more down-votes.

Comment: ok point taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A multipart layer is a simple list of singlepart layers:

You can use:

1) [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) and [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
import fiona
multis = fiona.open("multipolygons.shp")
# first feature of the shapefile
first = multis.next()
print first
{'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': [[[(244697.45179524383, 1000369.2307574936), (244827.15493968062, 1000373.0455558595), (244933.96929392271, 1000353.9715640305), (244933.96929392271, 1000353.9715640305), (244930.15449555693, 1000147.9724522779), (244697.45179524383, 1000159.4168473752), (244697.45179524383, 1000369.2307574936)]], [[(246082.22360202507, 1000453.1563215409), (246139.44557751188, 1000460.7859182726), (246189.03795626713, 1000403.5639427857), (246189.03795626713, 1000403.5639427857), (246086.03840039085, 1000132.7132588148), (245990.66844124615, 1000205.1944277647), (246082.22360202507, 1000453.1563215409)]]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', 1)])}
 # transform to shapely geometry
 multipol = shape(first['geometry'])
```

iterate through the geometries of multipol

```
 for poly in multipol:
      print poly 
  POLYGON ((244697.4517952438 1000369.230757494, 244827.1549396806 1000373.045555859, 244933.9692939227 1000353.971564031, 244933.9692939227 1000353.971564031, 244930.1544955569 1000147.972452278, 244697.4517952438 1000159.416847375, 244697.4517952438 1000369.230757494))
  POLYGON ((246082.2236020251 1000453.156321541, 246139.4455775119 1000460.785918273, 246189.0379562671 1000403.563942786, 246189.0379562671 1000403.563942786, 246086.0384003909 1000132.713258815, 245990.6684412461 1000205.194427765, 246082.2236020251 1000453.156321541))
```

2) PyQGIS in the console

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
# first feature of the shapefile
first = layer.getFeatures().next()
# the geometry
multipol = first.geometry()
```

iterate through the geometries of the Multipolygon

```
for poly in multipol.asMultiPolygon():
     print poly
[[(244697.45179524383, 1000369.2307574936), (244827.15493968062, 1000373.0455558595), (244933.96929392271, 1000353.9715640305), (244933.96929392271, 1000353.9715640305), (244930.15449555693, 1000147.9724522779), (244697.45179524383, 1000159.4168473752), (244697.45179524383, 1000369.2307574936)]]
[[(246082.22360202507, 1000453.1563215409), (246139.44557751188, 1000460.7859182726), (246189.03795626713, 1000403.5639427857), (246189.03795626713, 1000403.5639427857), (246086.03840039085, 1000132.7132588148), (245990.66844124615, 1000205.1944277647), (246082.22360202507, 1000453.1563215409)]]
```

And

```
print QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(poly).exportToWkt()
POLYGON((246082.22360202507115901 1000453.15632154094055295,246139.44557751188403927 1000460.78591827256605029,246189.03795626712962985 1000403.5639427857240662,246189.03795626712962985 1000403.5639427857240662,246086.03840039085480385 1000132.71325881476514041,245990.66844124614726752 1000205.19442776474170387,246082.22360202507115901 1000453.15632154094055295))
```

And it is is easy to create a new shapefile (Fiona, PyQGIS) or a layer (PyQGIS) with these results

3) or the PyQGIS processing module as in [Run ftools multiparts to singleparts from PYQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93018/run-ftools-multiparts-to-singleparts-from-pyqgis/93057#93057)`

Comment: the linked post was the answer that worked for me